# HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden. wget with python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pdf, wget

I am using Python with Jupyter Notebook.
This program downloads many pdfs and works on other machines, however when putting it on another machine with Windows Server 2016 Standard it shows an error.

The function that is causing the error is:

```
def download_doc(pasta_pdf,base_links):
    os.chdir(pasta_pdf)
    for link in base_links['Link_Download_Regulamento']:
        if link != None:           
            wget.download(link)
        else:
            continue

download_doc(pasta_origem,df_regulamentos_novos)
```

The error print:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ba9q6.png)

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Well the error is obvious: you are not authenticated.

Comment: I'm authenticated, only above 10 documents, that the error occours.

Answer (score 0):

You got

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

If you got information about HTTP response status code, but do not know what it does mean, then you might consult [developer.mozilla.org docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status), in this case this is [`403 Forbidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/403)

> The client does not have access rights to the content; that is, it is
> unauthorized, so the server is refusing to give the requested
> resource. Unlike 401, the client's identity is known to the server.